# facebooksdk.framework cordova iOS error

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, cordova, sdk

everyone!

So... I just made an app using cordova to compile an xcode project. Ok.

The app works fine, when the facebookSDK.framework isn't in the project. The pages does not load just because the user has to be logged into facebook. Whatever... But when I insert the facebookSDK.framework (downloaded from developers.facebook.com), I got a Build Fail and the following error:

```
ld: 475 duplicate symbols for architecture i386

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I tried to compile via terminal using -verbose and I saw that some files were not found in the cordova path:




myproject/Classes/MainViewController.h:28:9: fatal error: 'Cordova/CDVViewController.h' file not found

myproject/Classes/AppDelegate.h:30:9: fatal error: 'Cordova/CDVViewController.h' file not found

myproject/Classes/MainViewController.h:28:9: fatal error: 'Cordova/CDVViewController.h' file not found

myproject/Classes/AppDelegate.h:30:9: fatal error: 'Cordova/CDVViewController.h' file not found

myproject/Plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/FacebookConnectPlugin.h:12:9: fatal error: 'Cordova/CDV.h' file not found
```

I tried a lot of tutorials that I found in stackoverflow and google but nothing.

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks!

Comment: CDVViewController.h file is missing from your project

Comment: exactly! but I can't find how to solve this, insert this into my project and even download it... or any way to make my app build with no errors.